# mysql connector c++ convert string to wchar

Tags: c++, string, wchar

how can I convert a std::string (result from mysql select query)
to WCHAR?

already tryed this:

```
(wchar_t)app->db->getString("CharName")
```

but I get error

> no suitable conversation from std::string to wchar_t exists

Comment: Did you do any research? Or did you post here when your one guess failed?

Comment: of course I searched but I couldnt find any helpful solution or some solution were really bad so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11, use `std::wstring_convert`:

```c++
#include <locale>
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> converter;
std::wstring result = converter.from_bytes(app->db->getString("CharName"));
```

If not, you can resort to C functions like `mbstowcs()` and convert to the appropriate standard string type.